# How to add certificate for sub-domain using Lets Encrypt

Tags: ssl, encryption, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I have an NGINX server where I am trying to add SSL using Let's Encrypt .

My development settings are as follows:

```
url : dev.domain.in
root: /var/www/dev/html
```

The Production is as follows:

```
url : domain.in
root: /var/www/production/html
```

So in my nginx default page I have two server blocks one for development and another for production

I want to give one certificate for both the servers.

I know according to the Let's Encrypt website the command is as follows

> cd /opt/letsencrypt ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot
>   --webroot-path=/usr/share/nginx/html -d example.com -d www.example.com

But this can be done only if the SUBDOMAIN has the same webroot which not true in my case.

So how I can add the CERT for both here

Please help me out

Comment: Time to give a feedback?

Answer (score 12):

I use a common webroot across all of my virtual hosts on my nginx box.

```
/opt/certbot/certbot-auto certonly --webroot --agree-tos -w /srv/www/letsencrypt/ \
-d example.com,www.example.com
```

... and in nginx I have `snippets/letsencrypt.conf`:

```
location ~ /.well-known {
    root /srv/www/letsencrypt;
    allow all;
}
```

... which gets included in my server block for each site.

The files in the .well-known directory are temporary - they only exist for long enough for the authorisation process to complete and are then removed.

Once registration is successful, I then include the certificate definition in the server block via `include ssl/example.com.conf;` where that file contains the following:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
```

... along with the relevant listen directives to enable SSL on port 443.

You can include the same definition in multiple server blocks.

I have additional subdomains as SANs in my certificate as well and I have separate server blocks for `example.com`, `www.example.com` and also other subdomains like `click.example.com` - all using the same certificate.

Comment: Found this extremely useful. Saves a lot of typing, and simplifies the letsencrypt command. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Let´s Encrypt webroot method uses a file on your webroot directory named ".well-known/acme-challenge". You can configure a location snippet on your dev and main server to point to another webroot just for this file.

Something like:

```
   location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /etc/letsencrypt/webrootauth/.well-known/acme-challenge;
        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*) {
            add_header Content-Type application/jose+json;
        }
    }
```

And point your webroot as `--webroot-path /etc/letsencrypt/webrootauth`

This [discussion](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/using-the-webroot-domain-verification-method/1445/7) can help

Or you can use standalone method and do some work by hand.

Comment: You might add access-control to have this directory readable by world (challenge servers might change ip), if you have some sites with access-control, like development sites or admin sites restricted by password or ip.

This directory only holds the challenge/response for a short time, and with an unpretictable name, so no security risc here.